# Sending PUSH firebase notifications not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, firebase, browser, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase push sdk to receive and send notifications to users.

The serviceWorker is correct and messages are received correctly. However, I can't send notifications from my wordpress site. They return as sent but do not reach users.

If I send the notifications from my localhost, with the same code, they reach the user perfectly. Sometimes, when I send it through wordpress it works only once (first) and doesn't work the following times.

I imported the following firebase libraries (I was using version 7, but I saw in some forums that it had some bugs):
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-messaging.js

```
// API FIREBASE
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = [
    "notification" => [
        "title" => "$title",
        "body"  => "$message"
    ],
    "priority" => "high",
    "to" => "$token"
];

$ch = curl_init($url);

$serverKey = "myKey";
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization:key=' . $serverKey;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $err ? $err : $response;
```

**I hosted the code on another platform to send via get method.**

https://push.site.com.br/?title=mytitle&message=mymsg&token=mytoken

Ex.: [https://push.site.com.br/?title=Agendamento+Atendido&message=Jorge+de+Souza+Junior+atendeu+o+agendamento++em+26%2F01%2F2023+%28Quinta-feira%29+às+19%3A30+de+.&token=eUWBOSANPqYYklv-c6a8z8%3AAPA91bGg3KeVU8saXg2WGG9wY5UhrolP0EBH009kp-K58cfHwA3el67lOPfPDW5R9HNJpOGNKy4v8ZtJgJfjF-O-d_2qYkg3G2YPdi91fFgDoft1uwFVdbJ75ylpTCKQ8B2f1HsuFhG-](https://push.site.com.br/?title=Agendamento+Atendido&message=Jorge+de+Souza+Junior+atendeu+o+agendamento++em+26%2F01%2F2023+%28Quinta-feira%29+%C3%A0s+19%3A30+de+.&token=eUWBOSANPqYYklv-c6a8z8%3AAPA91bGg3KeVU8saXg2WGG9wY5UhrolP0EBH009kp-K58cfHwA3el67lOPfPDW5R9HNJpOGNKy4v8ZtJgJfjF-O-d_2qYkg3G2YPdi91fFgDoft1uwFVdbJ75ylpTCKQ8B2f1HsuFhG-)

However, even using file_get_contents with PHP, it only works the first time.

Returns the json stating that the message was sent but does not appear in push notifications.

[responnse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Hr6.png)

> {"multicast_id":4482522987560186854,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"7f2dd16a-c980-4558-87c7-8b041054a25c"}]}

If I send it from another site that doesn't have wordpress, it arrives normally. Regardless of how many times I send it. However, if I send it from my site, it doesn't reach the user (it happens only once and then it stops). Always returning the same "success":1 in the response.

Comment: If I open the site in a new tab, it sends the push notification normally.